# Error while updating the database as product is sold it should be updated in stock database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am practicing Python GUI with SQLite and I would like to update the quantity in the stock database as the item is sold as in my main program. But it gives me an error. I have created a button to call this function.

```py
def update_stock():
    with sqlite3.connect("stock.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE stock SET qty = qty - ? WHERE prodname = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql, (quantity,name))
     db.commit()
```

**Error Image**
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `quantity`?

Comment: quantity is a variable which is taking its value from a text box quantity=ItemQuantity.get() and all the product names and quantity are saved in txt file.

Comment: Obviously `quantity` and `name` are local variables defined in other function and they cannot be accessed in `update_stock()` function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Pooja! I'd recommend something like https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables to brush up on local variables. I'm assuming that's what `quantity` is in another function.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `quantity` variable is outside of the scope of `update_stock`. Try changing the signature of `update_stock` to receive the `quantity` and `name` arguments and the call `update_stock` with those arguments. For example:

```
def update_stock(quantity, name):
```

And where you call it:

```
update_stock(quantity, name)
```